# How do I apply event function to all input fields? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: function, events, input

I want to apply an event function to all relevant input fields with the same class. However, when I try solutions I've found on the web, I get feedback that 'e' is not defined. Below is the function I would like to apply to input fields with the class name 'blah' and it works well. How can I do this cleanly so I don't have to rewrite the function for each input field? Thank you.

```
x.addEventListener("keydown",function checkKey(e){
  let hpKeyCode = e.keyCode;
  let keyPos = e.target.selectionStart;
  for(let i=0; i<e.target.value.length;i++){
  if(e.target.value[i]==="," && keyPos==i+1 && hpKeyCode==8){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.selectionStart = keyPos-1;
    e.target.selectionEnd = keyPos-1;
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't see how `e` could be `undefined` in the first example. The second example doesn't even try to read `e`. Presumably the problem comes from a different part of your code. Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve] that you have **tested to ensure it reproduces the problem**. Use the [live demo feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) of the question editor.

Comment: @Quentin how would you apply that function to all input fields with class name 'blah'? The function is currently looking at one specific event with input at a single element. How do I apply to all input fields cleanly without rewriting the function for each input element?

Comment: When people ask you to provide a real [mcve], deleting half your attempt and then asking them to provide you with a ready baked solution isn’t appropriate.